# Do we need to secure the cookie .ASPXANONYMOUS

Tags: asp.net, security, cookies

could you please advise do we need to secure the cookie.ASPXANONYMOUS or not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a cookie that stores a unique ID for anonymous users for which you can use to track data against for individual users. More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.anonymousid(v=vs.110).aspx

By secure, do you mean setting the [secure flag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag)?

This depends. If you are storing sensitive information for your anonymous users and your site uses HTTPS anywhere this information is accessed then yes, it is a good idea. Usually you would only store sensitive information for identified users, but I guess that an anonymous token could sometimes contain information that attackers may like to retrieve (e.g. if the anonymous shopping baskets sometimes contained money off vouchers, it might be worthwhile for an attacker to hijack these sessions to steal them).

Answer (score 7):

If you determine that the anonymous user cookie should be secured to SSL only then you can adjust that in the web.config with the [anonymousIdentification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91ka2e6a%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) element.

```
<anonymousIdentification  
   enabled="true"
   cookieRequireSSL="true"
/>
```

> **cookieRequireSSL**
>   Specifies whether the cookie requires a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) connection when it is transmitted to the client. Because ASP.NET sets the authentication cookie property, Secure, the client does not return the cookie unless an SSL connection is in use.
>   The default is *false*.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @silverlightfox here that goes into whether you are storing any information for your anonymous no longer holds. These days (with the major browsers starting to warn users of all sites that aren't served over HTTPS) you *should* secure this cookie and all other cookies.