# Reading cookies in VB with an encrypted cookie from php

Tags: php, vb.net, encryption, cookies

I have a VB.NET website that needs to be called from a php script and will be passed a cookie in the header. First some code samples and my question is at the end.

php calling script:

```
    <form name="WIP" method="post" action="https://somesite.space/defaulttest.aspx" id="new_user_session" target="_blank">
    <input type="input" id="user_session_username_input" name="user_session[username]"  value='<?php echo $_COOKIE["username"];?>' />
    <input type="input" id="user_session_password_input" name="user_session[password]"  value='<?php echo $_COOKIE["password"];?>' />
    <button type="submit" name="callwip">hidden submit button</button>
    </form>
```

PHP script to display header info:

```
    <?php
    function getRequestHeaders() {
        $headers = array();
        foreach($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
            if (substr($key, 0, 5) <> 'HTTP_') {
                continue;
            }
            $header = str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', strtolower(substr($key, 5)))));
            $headers[$header] = $value;
        }
        return $headers;
    }
    
    $headers = getRequestHeaders();
    
    foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
        echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
        
        echo htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE["name"]) ,
    }
```

The PHP script displays
the cookie as such:

> Cookie:ASPXANONYMOUS=zJOR0PPn1wEkAAAANTM4MjVmNTgtNjBmZi00OTE5LWJhMDctMzZhNDE2MzNiMjhmJMtw8PE9cOVf21RLcsEj_oGjnQk1

VB test script:

```
    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Imports DataHelper
    
    Partial Class _Default
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    
        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            lblnameText.Text = Request.QueryString("id")
            lblpasswordText.Text = Request.QueryString("name")
            lblWelcomeText.Text = Request.AnonymousID
        End Sub
    End Class
```

The .aspx for the vb code just has 3 labels for testing purposes. I read somewhere that I needed to use Request.AnonymousID to get the cookie data. All I get is what looks like a GUID:9b203463-6c26-4f72-ba42-58c6d069447c. The Request.QueryString("id") and Request.QueryString("name") return nothing.
Nothing like the cookie I seen in the php test results which could well be my name and password values encrypted.

Finally for my question, I assume the calling script is encrypting the data somehow though I don't see where it happens. How do I decrypt it or even get the encrypted string in VB?

I think I am missing a thing or 20...
BTW this is my first time using cookies as well as the first time from one language to another.

Comment: Assuming the user submits the form, you'll find the username and password in `Request.Form` collection, not query string. But passing sensitive information from server to browser is a bad idea.

Comment: Really hard to understand your question. There is no "encrypted cookie from PHP" here. The `ASPXANONYMOUS` cookie is created by ASP.NET, not PHP.

Comment: @Olivier, the ASPXANONYMOUS cookie was displayed by the PHP script above, no ASP.NET involved at that point. I was finally able to get VB.NET to show me the cookie, but I'm still looking for how to decode it in VB. Or is that even necessary? I am getting the passed variables from the Request.Form collection as Salman suggested.

Comment: @Salman A, good point about the form collection. Passing that way may be less than ideally secure but requested by my customer. The user is logged in on their main site and is navigating to my site without needing to log in again. My site will require https so it will be encrypted.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Person logs into a php website by entering user/pass? Then sometime later he visits an aspx page? That page requires login but you don't want the person to enter the information again? Are both scripts hosted on same hostname? Is there a database that both scripts can share?

Comment: @MarkClark The [ASPXANONYMOUS cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20140988/12763954) is created by ASP.NET (as should be obvious by the name).

Comment: @Salman A I guess, at this point, I'm trying to crawl out of the rabbit hole that I even NEED to decode the cookie. I'm now mainly curious what it contains.The user logs into the php site. Then if they click the link to my site (VB.NET on different host) they don't need to log in again. No shared database.

Comment: @Olivier the name sure seems to imply that it is created by ASP/ASP.NET but the cookie is generated in a PHP to PHP call. I created the receiving PHP script  to see the contents of the headers. Again, no ASP.NET involved. At this point, I'm just quite curious what data is encrypted in the cookie.